# XBee S2 ZigBee reading digital input

Tags: at-command, gpio, xbee, zigbee

I currently have one XBee S2 and configure it as 'ZigBee Router AT' using X-CTU by USB to UART converter that's connect to my PC.

I want to be able to use the digital I/O of XBee instead of using another external MCU(like Arduino). For testing purpose, I set the 'AD02 = Digital input' and connect it with a switch along with a pull down resistor.

So how do I read the reading of the digital input of XBee? I check at the console and nothing comes up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ATIS` command will sample the inputs.  If you have more than one XBee module, you can configure the remote unit to periodically send sample data, and even trigger samples when an input changes.  It might be possible to configure the local device as the target (set `ATDH` to the value of `ATSH` and `ATDL` to `ATSL`) to receive periodic samples locally.

Digi has a Knowledge Base Article that covers details on [Digital and Analog input sampling](http://knowledge.digi.com/articles/Knowledge_Base_Article/Digital-and-analog-sampling-using-XBee-radios).

Comment: Is it possible to program xbee gpio pins with logic? something like Arduino digital pins